# UITextView uncheck Selectable checkbox cause text issues in runtime

Tags: ios, xcode6, uitextview, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

Using text view in storyboard you can make it not editable or not selectable next to Behavior caption or vice versa:

[image]

Seems options looks very promising and it works good for editable option. But when I uncheck selectable checkbox it cause some issues with font and text in runtime. So let's say that I set font to **Helvetica-Bold** and set color **Red** (which are not default settings for text view) and then uncheck selectable box like on image above. Next let me add some code to viewDidLoad:

```
self.theSameTextViewIamTalkingAbout.text = @"some text";
```

So when I am running my application I see that text change back to the default font and to the black color which is the default color.

I am not sure if this checkbox reset text view to the default appearance settings, but it changes text color and font text as you can see on my video as well:

[HERE IS MY VIDEO LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JxE2taV2ng&feature=youtu.be)

My question also how can I make it not selectable?

Comment: I have test it and you are right to get Storyboard settings we must have to enable `Editable` and `Selectable` properties. Weird !!

Comment: @Kampai, yep, totally Weird! )), seems like a bug

Comment: Keep selectable checked in storyboard and in viewDidLoad add self.theSameTextViewIamTalkingAbout.selectable = NO;

Answer (score 0):

Try to change font and font color in code. It's help for me.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically set isSelectable -> true and set font what ever you want

**Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8**

```
self.txtView?.isSelectable = true

self.txtView?.font =  UIFont (name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 16)
```