# How to make UITextView size same size on iPad (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, viewcontroller

I have a textview on a viewcontroller. I set all the text in code and when I run it on iPhone, it looks good and the text is a good size. When I run it on iPad, the text is really small. How can I make the text size bigger for the iPad screen?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I had the 'selectable' box unchecked. Not sure what it means but it fixed it.

Comment: Seems like a bug that's been around for a while... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635439/uitextview-uncheck-selectable-checkbox-cause-text-issues-in-runtime